# Java time formatting

Tags: java, datetime

I have the method

```
public static void testDateFormat() throws ParseException {
    DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date hora;
    hora=dateFormat.parse("00:00:01");
    System.out.println(hora.getHours()+" "+hora.getMinutes());
    System.out.println("Date "+hora);
    System.out.println("Seconds "+TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(hora.getTime()));
}
```

The output is

```
0 0
Date Thu Jan 01 00:00:01 COT 1970
Seconds 18001
```

Why the number of seconds is 18001? I expected to get 1 second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your `Date` has a `TimeZone` that is not UTC. It is, in fact, [COT](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/sa/cot.html) - which is UTC-5. And 5*60*60 is 18000 (or your result, plus one second). To get the value you expect, you could call [`DateFormat#setTimeZone(TimeZone)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) like,

```
DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // <-- Add this.
Date hora=dateFormat.parse("00:00:01");
System.out.println(hora.getHours()+" "+hora.getMinutes());
System.out.println("Date "+hora);
System.out.println("Seconds "+TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(hora.getTime()));
```

Output is as you expect.

**Edit**
As noted in the comments, [`Date#getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) per the Javadoc

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this `Date` object.

And your `Date` of

```
Thu Jan 01 00:00:01 COT 1970
```

is equivalent to

```
Thu Jan 01 00:05:01 UTC 1970
```

and thus you get the 5 hour difference.

Comment: And the important detail, which you really should mention, is that the `getTime()` method of `Date` returns the number of milliseconds since `00:00:00 1/1/1970 UTC` - which of course is `19:00:00 31/12/1969 COT`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Edited. Better?

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26415270/642706) is correct.

## Time-Only

But if you are working with time-only without date or time zone, then use a date-time library that can handle that explicitly rather than hacking the java.util.Date class.

## `LocalTime`

Use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the java.time package in Java 8. Both offer a [`LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) class.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( "00:00:01" );
int minuteOfHour = localTime.getMinuteOfHour();
```